# VIM, how to prevent indent on next comment line (Tcl file mode)

Tags: vim, tcl, comments, indentation

When I type a comment in my Tcl code, like so:

```
# Foo
```

And then hit Enter, I get this:

```
# Foo<Enter>
  # <cursor_here_now>
```

I want it to do this instead:

```
# Foo<Enter>
# <cursor_here_now>
```

Or:

```
  # Foo<Enter>
  # <cursor_here_now>
```

Relevant .vimrc settings:

```
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
set autoindent
set textwidth=0
set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set shiftround
```

I don't want to disable anything that I presently have. I just want to change the way comment indenting works. Honestly, I can't imagine why anyone would want it the way it works now. Wouldn't everyone want the next comment line to start in the same column as the previous one??

I have Googled a lot and tried a lot of combinations of formatoptions, autoindent, smartindent. I have consulted web pages such as: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code#File-type_based_indentation

But so far, nothing I try is stopping this weird behavior.

Thanks!
--Myles

PS VIM version 8.1.1. More details requested on version. Adding here.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun 19 2018 04:05:25)
Included patches: 1
Compiled by matrix@vlsj-ctrh65
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
+balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
+browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +timers
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +title
+channel           +iconv             +packages          +toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +user_commands
+clientserver      +job               -perl              +vertsplit
+clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +virtualedit
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +visual
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +visualextra
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +viminfo
+comments          +libcall           +python            +vreplace
+conceal           +linebreak         -python3           +wildignore
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +wildmenu
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +windows
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +writebackup
+cursorshape       -lua               -ruby              +X11
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        -xfontset
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +xim
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       +xpm
+dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       +xsmp_interact
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +statusline        +xterm_clipboard
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xterm_save
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +syntax            
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/grid/common/pkgs/vim/v8.1/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1                                                                                                 
Linking: gcc -std=gnu99   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lelf -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr    -L/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.6/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

Comment: What is your exact version? Is it really 8.1 + patch 1?

Comment: More version details added as requested.